# PHPMailer form sends after correct email without stopping to check fields that are still empty

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to develop a contact form using PHPMailer and validating with server-side for the purpose of this question. (javascript validation will be done later).

so I have added the post variables with sanitization and validate empty fields for each field in order.

It validates successfully for the name entered and the email when it is entered correctly, but when I press submit to test the subject and message fields if they are empty, it sends the form before it ever validates the subject and the message fields.

Somehow when it throws the catch exception for the email when it is successful, it sends the form while disregarding the rest of the form.

I am following tutorials, but I dont have solid answers as to why this is happening in my case.

Any ideas will be great help.

P.S. the hidden phone input field is for honeypot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="content">
    <?php

    // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
    // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    use phpmailer\phpmailer\PHPMailer;
    use phpmailer\phpmailer\SMTP;
    use phpmailer\phpmailer\Exception;

    require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';

    if (empty($_POST['phone'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['sendmail'])) {

            $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            if (empty($name)) {
                echo '<p class="error">Please enter your name</p>';
            }

            if (empty($email)) {
                echo '<p class="error">Please enter your email</p>';
            }

            if (empty($subject)) {
                echo '<p class="error">Please enter your subject</p>';
            }

            if (empty($message)) {
                echo '<p class="error">Please enter your message</p>';
            }

            // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            try {
                //Server settings
                //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                                    // Enable verbose debug output
                $mail->isSMTP();                                                                                    // Send using SMTP
                $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Set the SMTP server to send through
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username   = 'email';                                // SMTP username
                $mail->Password   = 'password';                                         // SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;             // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
                $mail->Port       = 587;                                                                    // TCP port to connect to

                //Recipients
                $mail->setFrom('email', 'Custom Form');
                $mail->addAddress($email, $name);                                                   // Add a recipient

                $mail->addReplyTo('email');

                // Attachments
                //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');                     // Add attachments

                // body content
                $body = "<p>Enquiry from: " . ucwords($name) . "<br> Message: " . $message . "</p>";

                // Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Name = 'Website enquiry from:' . $name;                      // Set email format to HTML
                $mail->Subject = $subject;
                $mail->Body = $body;
                $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

                $mail->send();
                echo '<p class="success">Your message has been sent!</p>';
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "<p class='error'>Message could not be sent. <br> Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}</p>";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <!-- <p class="success">Your message has been sent!</p>
        <p class="error">Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: </p> -->
    <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Enter subject line" maxlength="50">
        <textarea type="textarea" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" maxlength="6000" rows="4">Test mail using PHPMailer</textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="phone">
        <button type="submit" name="sendmail">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: surely the javascript validation comes before the PHP???

Comment: If a user fails to enter a valid email address or $email is empty the script can continue processing regardless. The same holds true for the other user supplied data. You ought to only proceed if these variables are set correctly

Comment: Just outputting an error message does NOT stop a script from proceeding :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly ah, okay. Silly of me. How can I stop the script from submitting then if the email is correct, though the subject and message have not been checked if empty before submitting properly? I think the reason it submits and disregards my checks is because the phpmailer only validates the email by default. is that right?

Comment: Side note: `<textarea type="textarea"....>` - textarea has no type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly rattled through the above and re-factored it slightly so that errors found during processing are recorded to an `errors` array - the mail will not be sent if this array is not empty. this remains untested but I hope will illustrate a possible method to adopt for ensuring the user has supplied the necessary data

```
<?php

    $errors=array();
    $status=false;

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && empty( $_POST['phone'] ) ) {
        if( isset( 
            $_POST['sendmail'],
            $_POST['name'],
            $_POST['email'],
            $_POST['subject'],
            $_POST['message']
        ) ) {
            $args=array(
                'name'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'email'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL,
                'subject'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'message'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
            );
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );

            $email=filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );


            if( empty( $name ) )$errors[]='Please enter your name';
            if( empty( $email ) )$errors[]='Please enter a valid email address';
            if( empty( $subject ) )$errors[]='Please enter your subject';
            if( empty( $message ) )$errors[]='Please enter your message';

            if( empty( $errors ) ){
                use phpmailer\phpmailer\PHPMailer;
                use phpmailer\phpmailer\SMTP;
                use phpmailer\phpmailer\Exception;

                require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
                require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
                require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';   


                // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                try {
                    //Server settings
                    //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                    // Enable verbose debug output
                    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
                    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Set the SMTP server to send through
                    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
                    $mail->Username   = 'email';                                // SMTP username
                    $mail->Password   = 'password';                             // SMTP password
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
                    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                    //Recipients
                    $mail->setFrom('email', 'Custom Form');
                    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);                           // Add a recipient

                    $mail->addReplyTo('email');

                    // body content
                    $body = "<p>Enquiry from: " . ucwords($name) . "<br> Message: " . $message . "</p>";

                    // Content
                    $mail->isHTML(true);
                    $mail->Name = 'Website enquiry from:' . $name;               // Set email format to HTML
                    $mail->Subject = $subject;
                    $mail->Body = $body;
                    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

                    $status=$mail->send();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $errors[]="<p class='error'>Message could not be sent. <br> Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}</p>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <?php
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
                    if( !empty( $errors ) ){
                        foreach( $errors as $error )printf('<p class="error">%s</p>', $error );
                    }
                    if( $status ){
                        echo '<p class="success">Your message has been sent!</p>';
                    }
                }
            ?>  
            <form role="form" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Enter subject line" maxlength="50">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" maxlength="6000" rows="4">Test mail using PHPMailer</textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="phone">
                <button type="submit" name="sendmail">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit: One comment to see by myself under their post ;-)

Comment: :-) wow, didn't even check the HTML so thanks for that... good spot!